# MS Excel how to undo multiple actions using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, undo

I am wondering if I can undo all the actions in the undo queue,

I know of the Application.Undo function but this only undoes the last action and clears the queue, I tried putting this in a loop and it just kept undoing then redoing.

Extra info:
Users open a form in read only,
Accidentally change fields then use a form that makes changes then saves it (in vba) and the accidental changes are saved too,
I want to undo all the accidental changes before the user runs the form so only the necessary changes are saved.

Can I undo multiple actions at once?

Comment: Are you trying to Undo all with VBA, or without?  Also, without some rather clever/complex coding, AFAIK, you can't "undo" a macro like you can with "CTRL+Z" if you delete a cell for instance.

Comment: I only want to undo anything the user has typed so only manual actions (no macros)

Comment: What version of Excel? In 2016 (and earlier I believe), you can go to the Undo, click the down arrow, and see the previous actions done and reverse those out. Are you only able to see the most recent action?

Comment: I am not the user, the users are unaware that they have typed anything and I would rather make the system robust than tell the user to stop making mistakes

Comment: what does this mean ? _before the user runs the form_

Comment: they press a button the a userForm pops up they type thing into the form then press a button on the form , so before the user form runs is really before they press the button to open the form or the button in the form(wasn't really sure how to phrase this)

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-undo-method-excel) says "This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before running the macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands."  Although it doesn't have to be the first line in the macro (AFAIK it just has to occur before VBA makes any changes itself), the bit about undoing only the **last** action is true.  If you don't want the users to make changes to the worksheets other than via the form, why not just protect the worksheet?

Comment: Its only a few users using this form and the rest of the users access it in read write mode and are allowed to update the data as they want, I think protecting the sheet will hinder the majority of users

Answer (score 0):

You can close your workbook without saving. This is the only method I am aware of. To avoid data loss run your macros on the copy of your data.

Basically, you can't undo anything after VBA runs...